# find count of substrings of all anagrams of 1st string that are anagram of 2nd

Tags: count, permutation, dynamic-programming

Need an approach to solve this problem!

Problem : Given two strings containing lowercase alphabets count number of matches modulo 10^9+7 of non intersecting substrings in all distinct anagrams of 1st string such that they are equal to any anagram of 2nd string.

Example :
1) String 1: "ABC", String 2: "AB"
Answer = 4
Explanation : 'ABC','BAC','CAB','CBA' all contribute 1 such match each.

2) String 1: "ABCAB", String 2: "AB"
Answer = 40
Explanation : One possible Anagram of string 1 'ABABC' for which match count is 2 that is 'AB' and 'AB' while 'BABCA' contributes only one match that is 'BA' or 'AB'.

Constraints :
n,m are lengths of first and second strings
0 < n < 200 
0 < m < 100

The approach I tried doing involved pre-computing the first 200 factorials modulo 10^9+7 and then from the given string calculating how many maximum non intersecting patterns (mx) the string could have and looping from p=1 to mx and calculating the number of rearrangements of first string that contain exactly p non intersecting substrings (i.e string 2) patterns.
Is there a different approach that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach you can use -

1)Calculate number of anagrams of string2. You can google permutations and combinations to get a method to do so (in O(1))(say x).

2)Calculate at most how many string2 can string1 contribute. This can be done by calculating how many times the character of your string repeat in string2. like in your second example 'A' and 'B' repeat twice in string two so you can get at most anagrams at one time.**Note -** If choose lowest number if the character frequency doesnt match. Like if for some string 'A' repeats thrice and 'B' twice you can get at most 2 anagrams so you take lowest repeating character's frequency.

3) Calculate answer using formulae of permutation and combination-

- Number of string1 anagrams with only one anagram of string2 `x*(n1-n2+1)` where n1 and n2 are lengths of string1 and 2 resp.
- With two anagrams - `(n1- 2*n2+2)*x*x`
- And so on